# Was that Warren Worthington III?

Tags: marvel, x-men, x-men-cinematic-universe, x-men-apocalypse

In the movie X-Men: Apocalypse, we see a character with wings that becomes one of Apocalypse's four horseman. I would have to assume that that's [Warren Worthington III aka Angel aka Archangel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warren_Worthington_III).

But, I don't think we ever heard a name or any sort of backstory for him whatsoever, which was odd. He was in a cage-fighting ring for some reason. That's pretty much all we got. What was the deal with that?

At both [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Men:_Apocalypse) and [IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3385516/), the character is credited as simply "Angel". Was it Warren, or a new character filling the same role?

Comment: Related question [Shouldn't Warren Worthington III be just a little child during X-Men Apocalypse?](http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/46607/shouldnt-warren-worthington-iii-be-just-a-little-child-during-x-men-apocalypse)

Answer (score 3):

While only credited as "Angel" in the film, actor Ben Hardy has participated in interviews where his character has been mentioned to be Warren Worthington III, such as this one:

- **[Space: Ben Hardy *X-Men Apocalypse* interview](http://www.space.ca/x-men-apocalypse-angel-ben-hardy-interview/)**

So the character is indeed Worthington III.

Comment: the article mentions the name 'warren worthington iii'. the interview itself does not. there is no acknowledgement of the name by anyone involved in the movie.

Answer (score 2):

During the cage fight, he is referred to by the ring announcer as Angel. But you’re quite right — we don’t get any details in the film about his given name or family background.