# What evidence is there that the two Moira MacTaggerts in the XCU are the same person?

Tags: marvel, x-men, x-men-cinematic-universe

We first encountered Moira MacTaggert in the 2006 *X-Men: The Last Stand*. The movie takes place sometime in the "near future" of the 2000's.

She appears to be a 30-something year old doctor on Muir Island. She is played by a then-36 year old Olivia Williams.

[image: Olivia-Moira supposedly 70-something years old]

In the 2011 *X-Men: First Class*, we meet Moira MacTaggert again. Here, she is 30-something, but this time is an American CIA agent in 1962. She is played by a then-32 year old Rose Byrne.

[image: Rose-Moira]

The X-Men Movies Wikia claims that [these two characters are the same person in-universe](http://xmenmovies.wikia.com/wiki/Moira_MacTaggert).

> Sometime after the events of First Class, MacTaggert left the CIA and ultimately became a medical scientist and doctor. She establishes her home and workplace on Muir Island in northern Scotland, and eventually works alongside Charles Xavier again — this time in an educational capacity.

But they provide no citation or explanation how the character would span the 40+ year time gap without aging.

The *Days of Future Past* timeline re-write is not likely a good answer here, as we catch up with Moira in 1983 during the events of *X-Men: Apocalypse*, where she is still a CIA agent.

### What evidence is there that these two versions of Moira depict the same in-universe character?

Comment: The continuity of the x-men universe is pretty bad. I'm not sure there is anything else to say on the matter

Comment: “The Days of Future Past timeline re-write is not likely a good answer here” — why not? Wibbley-wobbley, timey-wimey. One set of consequences of time-travel is as believable as the next, because in the real world, time travel doesn't exist. So unless you set rules about how it works (which the X-Men universe hasn't), anything's fair game. (In my head, Dr McTaggart just aged *incredibly* well by taking as good care of herself as she does of her patients.)

Answer (score 6):

## There's probably no evidence.

As has been discussed before on meta before, for example [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7394/3823), which is talking about Memory Alpha (the Star Trek wiki) (and I'm sure there is a better meta reference) but I can't find it now,  **fan-sourced wikis are not primary references**.     What we have here is an unsourced statement by a fan who merely connected the dots that there are two mentions of Moira MacTaggart with seemly irreconcilable differences and then made the statement:

> Sometime after the events of First Class, MacTaggert left the CIA and ultimately became a medical scientist and doctor. She establishes her home and workplace on Muir Island in northern Scotland, and eventually works alongside Charles Xavier again — this time in an educational capacity.

as you noted.

But in fact there's probably no evidence at all for that and it's just an inconsistency like many others.

The problem here is that someone on the Wiki took it upon themselves to take continuity in-universe too seriously and therefore make the conclusions they stated.   The attitude is essentially: *We saw these two things, that we must assume are true and consistent since we saw them, so I'm free to state as fact whatever explanation can make both things true*, regardless of how logical the result is.    (Note, they equally well could have just assumed there are two different Moira MacTaggarts and it would have been an equally valid conclusion -- but the default assumption is same name = same person.)

With this attitude, effectively any inconsistency becomes a factory for more and weirder inconsistencies -- instead of just accepting that the continuity is lacking.

---

[Here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8061/3823) is another answer talking about how wikias are **not primary sources** and are **fan written**.

Comment: I’m not sure your point is necessarily good evidence for your claims. “Wikis are fan written therefore this is fan written” doesn’t seem like the best standpoint to take. You could be right, but it’s unconvincing.

Comment: @Edlothiad:   I'm saying there's probably isn't any evidence and then giving the explanation -- what other answer can I give? -- particularly since this is almost certainly correct (unless demonstrated to be wrong).

Comment: The question is completely different and would warrant an answer if it were, for example, a canon statement.   But it's not, and it's very possible the poster isn't aware of the quality of statement in the wikias.   In other words, the premise of the question needs to be straightened.   If the poster knows this and asks anyways, then the answer is probably "there's no evidence" and you can ignore the rest of my answer.

Comment: I'm aware that there is a possibility this is correct, I'm not convinced this is a good argument though. That proving a negativity because "Someone said they're inaccurate" seems like circular logic, no? Some randomer said they're all inaccurate because they're written by randomers.

Comment: @Edlothiad:  I don't know what to say.   The poster is asking a question asking for the evidence that a pointless conclusion is true.

Comment: This is like asking "What is the evidence that the earth is flat?"   The answer is "There's isn't any."  .... and ... "The statement that the Earth is flat is based on a bunch of garbage for historical reasons, and possibly based on some weird psychological quirks about some people not being able to wrap their mind around being on the surface of a large sphere, and possibility because some people like to think they are special and smarter than others, and possibly human psychology is subject to poisoning by conspiracy theories."

Comment: But you're not going to get any answer that satisfies you if all you want is the evidence that doesn't exist.

Comment: Firstly, there is plenty of evidence the Earth isn't flat. The first is the horizon, without curvature = no horizon. In my opinion there is evidence for it, just none that you have found, whether the requirement is to tweet someone trying to ask them, email a director or fb message a crew member, is another matter. But simply saying "It's wrong because it could be made up" sounds made up.

Comment: @Edlothiad, there isn't evidence that the Earth **is** flat,  because isn't.   That was the point of my analogy.   The MacTaggarts can't be the same due merely to the time periods unless you posit some exotic scifi weirdness.   And the poster only asked the question because of some fan on a wiki overstepped.  So I stand by the answer.   I'm sorry if you aren't convinced,  but that's the answer (unless demonstrated otherwise. )

Comment: [Here's a question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/172325/13217) showing that third parties started reprinting fan-made stuff that people started posting on the Harry Potter Wiki.

Answer (score 2):

The best evidence we have is that she's not the only one to suffer from the seemingly inconsistent timelines. [Angel](http://xmenmovies.wikia.com/wiki/Angel) is an example of another character that is also subject to this, given his age and appearance in both 1983 and 2011. However, [only the 2011 version of the character is confirmed to be Warren Worthington III](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/131797/was-that-warren-worthington-iii).

A counter-example to Angel would be [Emma Frost](http://xmenmovies.wikia.com/wiki/Emma_Frost), who appeared in *X-Men: First Class* as an adult, but *Wolverine: Origins* as much younger. Despite the same first name and powers (and the implication of who they were), they were actually [cited by the executive producer as different people](http://xmenmovies.wikia.com/wiki/Emma_Frost).

The X-Men movie universe, and ultimately the comic universe as well, are commonly known to have a very loose relationship to time and aging. Given the history of such things, if anything their full name alone should be enough evidence to confirm they are in fact the same people. Unless explicit writer/director confirmation is given that they are not, it's usually safe to assume they are.

Comment: *Both versions of the character are confirmed to be Warren Worthington III.* There is no evidence there that they are. Read the article Praxis linked. The article writer claims it, but there is nothing to support it. Even official cast lists simply list the *Apocalypse* version simply as "Angel" while everyone else has both names.

Comment: *It would be more worthwhile looking for explicit writer/director confirmation that they are not (which given they chose the names they did for a reason, is highly unlikely).* That would be exactly the type of evidence we're looking for here.

Comment: @phantom42 Missed that comment, good point. Edited to reflect. Also looked into Emma Frost and added her as a notable counter-example (same first name, same powers, but cited as different characters).

Answer (score -2):

The answer is simple.

The first X-Men trilogy was in a different continuity/universe separated from
the X-Men First Class film series.

The depiction of a future in film "Days of Future Past" was a parallel universe of Patrick Stewart's Prof. X.